# streamlit app only executing successfully for one cycle and hanging after that

Tags: python, streamlit

I have `streamlit` app where on the sidebar I have following sections:

```
1. File uploader
2. 3 buttons - Submit, reset, add new row
3. Row(s) of input text area in Key value manner
```

Now at first there is only single row of point 3 when the app initiates, user enters key and value data and can click on `add new row` button to add another set of key value data. Then the user `submits` and gets the results. Now once the result is done, I want the user to be able to add another row to already visible input key value row data or click `Reset` to reset to first stage (single empty row of input key value box), but this is not working and the app just hangs and goes in loop.

Here is my current code:

```
import streamlit as st

key_dict = {}

# Initialize the key in session state
if 'clicked' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.clicked = {"submit": False, "reset": False}

if 'input_keys' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.input_keys = [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) + str(random.randint(0, 999999))]

# Function to update the value in session state
def clicked(button):
    st.session_state.clicked[button] = True



def sidebar_section():

    c1,c2 = st.sidebar.columns(2)

    c1.write("Main Area")
    new_sec = c2.button("Add New Row")


    if new_sec:
        st.session_state.input_keys.append(
            random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) + str(random.randint(0, 999999)))

    h1, h2 = st.sidebar.columns(2)
    index = 1
    for input_key in st.session_state.input_keys:

        Key = h1.text_input(f"Input 1 {index}", placeholder="Enter Key",
                              key=input_key)
        val = h2.text_input(f"Input 2 {index}", placeholder="Enter Value",
                              key=input_key + "input")
        key_dict[Key] = val
        index += 1

    return key_dict


file = st.sidebar.file_uploader('Upload', type=["pdf", "txt"])

key_dict = sidebar_section()
st.sidebar.markdown("---")
c1, c2 = st.sidebar.columns([1, 1])
clear = c1.button("Reset", on_click=clicked, args=["reset"], use_container_width=True)
generate = c2.button("Submit", on_click=clicked, args=["submit"], use_container_width=True)


if st.session_state.clicked["reset"]:
    placeholder = st.empty()
    st.session_state.input_keys = [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) + str(random.randint(0, 999999))]
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "F5")


if st.session_state.clicked["submit"]:
    print("Inside Submit buttons \n")
    #Check if file was uploaded
    if file is not None:

        # Save uploaded file to 'F:/tmp' folder.
        save_folder = '.'
        save_path = Path(save_folder, file.name)
        with open(save_path, mode='wb') as w:
            w.write(file.getvalue())



        placeholder.empty()
        # links_list = links.split(",")

        print("length of Key Dict = {}".format(len(key_dict)))
        with st.spinner("Loading Results ! "):
            print("Inside Generate button and Uploaded file is not none. Going to get results \n")
            #Perform local computation
        #Display result using st.write()
```

Not sure where the issue is, though I know its related to somehow not retaining last state of button and inputs, and how to correct it.

Comment: have you noticed that you return key_dict in sidebar_section instead of Key_dict (with upper K)?

Comment: @Ze'evBen-Tsvi sorry that's a typo. Corrected it

Answer (score 0):

### Use random keys wisely

I would not do random keys like that; it's not necessary and it introduces the (very small) possibility of a duplicate. You can just use integers as keys (though Streamlit will recast them as strings when used directly as keys for widgets).

### When to make buttons stateful or not

If you want to click a button and have some things display and continue to display as the user moves around interacting with things, that's when you do something like the `clicked` function you have. This structure makes buttons "remember" that they were clicked past the immediate rerun.

If you are going to track a value in session state for something like a "Reset" button, you'll need to manually revert that value. The way you have it now, as soon as someone resets once, then the code will continue to reset over and over no matter what else the user does.

Generally speaking, if you want something to happen once and then go away, you can condition it directly on the button's output or put it in a callback function for the button. You wouldn't want something like a reset action to keep occurring, so you probably don't need to save some value in session state for that part.

In the first edited script below, I changed the reset action to a callback but left the submit action conditioned on the saved value in session state for demonstration. However, that means if the user changes one value in the sidebar, you'll see it jumps right into reprocessing the file because "submit" continues to be remembered. As such, see the extra modification in the second script to make sure computations don't get needlessly rerun.

### Where to put button logic

Right now, you have the function which generates all your input rows occurring before the lines that "reset" those rows. That means, when reset is clicked, the page will rerun with all of the pre-existing input rows and *then* it will do the work of resetting. At best you will get the appearance of "needing to click twice."

You can either use `st.experimental_rerun` to force the page to reload when it finishes that reset logic, or you can instead put that logic into a callback function. Callback functions run as a prefix to the page reloading so that would mean the input rows would display in their "reset state" immediately upon clicking reset.

### Basic correction

```py
import streamlit as st
from pathlib import Path
import time

key_dict = {}

# Initialize the key in session state
if 'clicked' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.clicked = {"submit": False}

if 'input_rows' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.input_rows = 1

# Function to update the value in session state
def clicked(button):
    st.session_state.clicked[button] = True

def reset():
    st.session_state.input_rows = 1
    st.session_state.clicked["submit"] = False
    # Manually clear the first row since the key is not random anymore
    st.session_state.key_1 = ''
    st.session_state.input_1 = ''

def sidebar_section():
    c1,c2 = st.sidebar.columns(2)

    c1.write("Main Area")
    new_sec = c2.button("Add New Row")

    if new_sec:
        st.session_state.input_rows += 1

    h1, h2 = st.sidebar.columns(2)
    for index in range(st.session_state.input_rows):
        Key = h1.text_input(f"Input 1 {index+1}", placeholder="Enter Key",
                              key=f'key_{index+1}')
        val = h2.text_input(f"Input 2 {index+1}", placeholder="Enter Value",
                              key=f'input_{index+1}')
        key_dict[Key] = val

    return key_dict

file = st.sidebar.file_uploader('Upload', type=["pdf", "txt"])

key_dict = sidebar_section()
st.sidebar.markdown("---")
c1, c2 = st.sidebar.columns([1, 1])
c1.button("Reset", on_click=reset, use_container_width=True)
c2.button("Submit", on_click=clicked, args=["submit"], use_container_width=True)

if st.session_state.clicked["submit"]:
    #Check if file was uploaded
    if file is not None:

        # Save uploaded file to 'F:/tmp' folder.
        save_folder = '.'
        save_path = Path(save_folder, file.name)
        with open(save_path, mode='wb') as w:
            w.write(file.getvalue())

        with st.spinner("Loading Results ! "):
            #Perform local computation
            time.sleep(5)
        st.success("Done!")
```

### Better correction (with submit also made into a callback)

```py
import streamlit as st
from pathlib import Path
import time

key_dict = {}

if 'input_rows' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.input_rows = 1

if 'result' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.result = None

# Function to update the value in session state
def clicked(button):
    st.session_state.clicked[button] = True

def clear_results():
    st.session_state.result = None

def reset():
    st.session_state.input_rows = 1
    st.session_state.clicked["submit"] = False
    clear_results()
    # Manually clear the first row since the key is not random anymore
    st.session_state.key_1 = ''
    st.session_state.input_1 = ''

def submit(file):
    if file is None:
        st.session_state.result = None
        return
    # Save uploaded file to 'F:/tmp' folder.
    save_folder = '.'
    save_path = Path(save_folder, file.name)
    with open(save_path, mode='wb') as w:
        w.write(file.getvalue())

    with st.spinner("Loading Results ! "):
        #Perform local computation
        time.sleep(5)
        result = "Anything you want to display as a result..."
    st.session_state.result = result
    return

def sidebar_section():
    c1,c2 = st.sidebar.columns(2)

    c1.write("Main Area")
    new_sec = c2.button("Add New Row")

    if new_sec:
        st.session_state.input_rows += 1

    h1, h2 = st.sidebar.columns(2)
    for index in range(st.session_state.input_rows):
        Key = h1.text_input(f"Input 1 {index+1}", placeholder="Enter Key",
                              key=f'key_{index+1}')
        val = h2.text_input(f"Input 2 {index+1}", placeholder="Enter Value",
                              key=f'input_{index+1}')
        key_dict[Key] = val

    return key_dict

file = st.sidebar.file_uploader('Upload', type=["pdf", "txt"])

key_dict = sidebar_section()
st.sidebar.markdown("---")
c1, c2 = st.sidebar.columns([1, 1])
c1.button("Reset", on_click=reset, use_container_width=True)
c2.button("Submit", on_click=submit, args=[file], use_container_width=True)

if st.session_state.result is not None:
    st.success("Done!")
    st.write(st.session_state.result)

st.button('Clear Results', on_click=clear_results)
```